# 'NoRowsOverlay' or 'overlayNoRowsTemplate' position is out of ag-grid columns or overlapping headers

Tags: html, angular, ag-grid

NoRowsOverlay / overlayNoRowsTemplate position is out of ag-grid columns or overlapping headers

Comment: Can you share a stackblitz.. there might be something with the css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

I added this in CSS for angular 4 project.

```
:host >>> .ag-overlay-no-rows-wrapper {
  padding-top: 5em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to style the ag-overlay class in my global scss styles. I removed the absolute positioning and added some margin for top and bottom:

```
.ag-overlay {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
  }
```